# OpenCV: is OpenCL actually enabled?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I'm trying to speed up the research of features of stitching algorithm using OpenCL. I'm using the code of the example provided here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp 
I read online that the only thing I have to do is change Mat to Umat. I did it.

However I am not sure my code is actually using OpenCL.

- First: I'm working on an Ubuntu 16.04
  Virtual Machine using Parallels
  Desktop on a Macbook Pro. Therefore
  the only device supported by OpenCL
  will be the CPU (no GPU). I installed the correct drivers, sdk, etc and CPU should work correctly. You can see the result of command "clinfo" in Ubuntu shell below. Working with a CPU, I do not
  expect performance improvement. My
  plan is just to work my virtual
  machine and than deploy the code on a
  real Ubuntu machine.
- Second: the code has no improvement (as expected, see above). Actually the required time seems to be the same. Is it right? I mean, I know I am working still on the CPU, but I expected to be some differences. Moreover **looking at the call graph profiled with grof and gprof2dot there no differences** (for ones who have never heard about gprof, it is simply a code profiler that can generate a call graph showing all calls among functions: which function calls what other function, and so on). Is it possible? OpenCV with and without OpenCL should call **exactly** the same function?

How can I be sure the code is actually working with OpenCL? I read online there were some bugs in features finding on OpenCL and therefore I would like to check myself. Moreover, obviously, I would like to work and edit the code, this is just the beginning.

I'm using this code to check if OpenCL is working:

```
void checkOpenCL() {

    if (!cv::ocl::haveOpenCL())
    {
        cout << "OpenCL is not available..." << endl;
        //return;
    }

    cv::ocl::Context context;
    if (!context.create(cv::ocl::Device::TYPE_ALL))
    {
        cout << "Failed creating the context..." << endl;
        //return;
    }

    cout << context.ndevices() << " CPU devices are detected." << endl; //This bit provides an overview of the OpenCL devices you have in your computer
    for (int i = 0; i < context.ndevices(); i++)
    {
        cv::ocl::Device device = context.device(i);
        cout << "name:              " << device.name() << endl;
        cout << "available:         " << device.available() << endl;
        cout << "imageSupport:      " << device.imageSupport() << endl;
        cout << "OpenCL_C_Version:  " << device.OpenCL_C_Version() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cv::ocl::Device(context.device(0)); //Here is where you change which GPU to use (e.g. 0 or 1)

}
```

And it prints:

```
1 CPU devices are detected.
name:              Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
available:         1
imageSupport:      1
OpenCL_C_Version:  OpenCL C 1.2
```

Running clinfo in Ubuntu shell report

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 (Build 25)
  Driver Version                                  1.2.0.25
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             2300MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     4
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Preferred work group size multiple              128
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 32      
    short                                                1 / 16      
    int                                                  1 / 8       
    long                                                 1 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8       
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              6103834624 (5.685GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1525958656 (1.421GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            95372416 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [INTEL]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run the `facedetect.cpp` from the opencv's T-API folder in the samples folder, it will tell you if you have OpenCL ON/OFF, displayed on the rendered window.

Here is how to run the command:

```
./ufacedetect --cascade=/home/user/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml /dev/video5 --scale=1.3
```

Comment: Shouldn't `opencv --opencl` tell you the same thing?